# Sides of a Right-angled Triangle

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

$$(2n + 1)^2 + (2n^2 + 2n)^2 = (2n^2 +2n +1)^2$$

It can be used to generate infinitely many sides of right-angled triangles with integer lengths by putting values of $n = 1, 2, 3, ... $

I wanted to know that how we came to this equation. How do we know that putting n = 1, 2, 3, … into this we'll get all the sides of a right-angled triangle. I'm trying to find more about this on the internet, if you can help me what should I find about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with the sequence of square numbers, and take all the differences between consecutive terms, you get all the odd numbers in sequence. For instance,
$$
2^2 - 1^2 = 3\\
3^2 - 2^2 = 5\\
4^2-3^3 = 7
$$
Some times, that odd number happens to be a square itself. For instance, we have
$$
5^2 - 4^2 = 9 = 3^2\\
13^2 - 12^2 = 25 = 5^2
$$
Rearranging these, we get Pythagorean triples:
$$
3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2\\
5^2 + 12^2 = 13^2
$$
If we want to describe all the different Pythagorean triples that appear this way, we end up with exactly your expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula notes that often Pythagorean Triples are of the form $(t_1, t_2, t_2+1)$. It attempts to see when this is the case and this formula generates that, we have:
$$(2n^2+2n+1)^2-(2n^2+2n)^2=4n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)^2$$

Since the difference here is just a square, it's a valid triple. However, this misses many triples, particularly multiples of existing triples, but an example is $(8,15,17)$. I prefer the usage of:

$$(p^2-q^2)^2+(2pq)^2=(p^2+q^2)^2$$
This is most notable for its link to complex numbers, it is $$\Re(z^2)+\Im(z^2)=|z^2|$$ and this can be used to generate them. Set your calculator to Complex mode and use $(1000\text{Ran#}+\text{1000Ran#}i)^2=$ and every result will be the base and height of a Pythagoras triangle.

(Ran# is my calculators random number generator, it might be different to yours. Also it generates from $0.001$ to $1$, max $3$dp, hence my multiplying by $1000$)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Primitive Pythagorean triple $(a, b, c)$. Consider $b=4T_n$ where $T_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ triangular number. Notice that if this is so, then the value of $c$ is $4T_n+1$.

Note that the formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ triangular number is given by $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. All that we are left to do is solve for $a$ from the following equation: $a^2+[4T_n]^2=[4T_n+1]^2$. Solving this gives the value of $a$ as $2n+1$. Hence, $(a, b, c)=(2n+1, 4T_n, 4T_n+1)$ is a Pythagorean triple.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula (I call it "yours" in reference to the post) is a special case of a formula I developed in 2009 and have occasionally posted here in answer to questions about Pythagorean triples.

\begin{equation}\qquad
  A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\qquad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\qquad C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2
\end{equation}

It generates the subset of triples where $GCD(A,B,C)$ is an odd square. The table below shows these sets where $n$ is the set number and $k$ is the "count" or member number within the set.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5   &  k=6  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 & 13,84,85 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 & 45,108,117 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 & 85,132,157 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 & 133,156,205 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 & 189,180,261 \\ \hline
\end{array}
If we let $n=1$, my formula becomes
$\quad A=(2k + 1)^2\quad B=(2k^2 + 2k)^2\quad C=(2k^2 +2k +1)^2\quad$ which matches yours exactly and generates the sub-subset $(Set_1)$ in the table above.

How developed? Notice that the difference $(d)=(C-B)=(2n-1)^2$ and the increment $(i)$ between values of $A$ is $2(2n-1)$. Now notice that $A$ is the sum of $(d)$ plus the increment $(i)$ times a multiplier $(k)$. From here, the B-function and C-function follow by substituting the now-known expressions for $A$ and $(C-B)$ into the Pythagorean theorem.